# python3: How can I add decimals that are inside a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, decimal

I am a beginner and I want to add the decimals inside the string `s`

```
 totalsum=0
 s='1.23 2.4 3.123'
 for a in s:
    totalsum=totalsum+float(a)
 print (totalsum)
```

but when i try it says

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'
```

How can I add those three decimals?

Comment: `sum(map(float, s.split()))` seems like it should do.

Answer (score 4):

you're iterating on every *character* of the string. It works at first (well, for `1`...), but when you reach `.` you get a parse error.

Now, you need to split your string. And be pythonic, do that in one line:

```
totalsum = sum(map(float,s.split()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s='1.23 2.4 -4.3 3.123 56'
data = sum(map(float, re.findall('(-*\d+\.*\d+)|\b-*\d+\b', s)))
```

Output:

```
58.453
```

Comment: that doesn't work with numbers like `1`. If there's no dot you're toast.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thank you for pointing that out. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: what about negative numbers? exponent (note: you're over-answering the question by trying to extract only valid floats from a string: this battle is lost :))

Answer (score 2):

You have to do like this , you are trying to add whole string to float. Instead you have to split and add them

```
   totalsum=0
    s='1.23 2.4 3.123'
    for a in s.split():
        totalsum=totalsum+float(a)
    print (totalsum)
```

Comment: it's not adding the whole string to float, it's adding all the characters of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your string.

```
totalsum=0
s='1.23 2.4 3.123'.split()
for a in s:
    totalsum =totalsum + float(a)
print (totalsum)
```

output:

```
6.753
```